# Import Module from file via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a series of Access Databases and I have a few modules that I'd like to keep current in each database.  Is there a way to import a code module into a database using VBA?

I have a similar project that locks databases each night:

```
    If fso.FileExists(rst!AppAddress) = True Then
        Set cycleDB = OpenDatabase(rst!AppAddress)
        If cycleDB.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = True Then
            cycleDB.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = False
        End If
```

Is there a way to import objects into a database this way?

Answer (score 0):

See if Application.LoadFromText method will be of any use to you. Finding the actual documentation might be tricky !